# Why does my SetPixel function not work in my PictureBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drawing, picturebox

I have a problem with SetPixel Function In VB.NET

I am trying to set a color of a specified place in the picturebox.

I want to make the point(X : 45,Y : 55) in the color red.

I searched for a function to do that. And I found SetPixel.

I wrote my code in a button.

This is my code :

```
Private Sub btn_Set_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Set.Click
  Dim pic1 As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
  pic1.SetPixel(45, 55, Color.Red)
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work. When I click on the button. nothing happens.

Why it doesn't work?

Note: there is no image in the picturebox. I just set a backColor to the picturebox.

Comment: the easiest way is to add a pictureboy and add the new image to it

Comment: @nbk I tried to add an image to the picturebox instead of set a backColor. But it doesn't work.

Comment: `CType(PictureBox1.Image, Bitmap).SetPixel(...)` (i.e., don't create a new Bitmap)

Comment: "When I click on the button. nothing happens." Something did happen. You created a new, INVISIBLE, Bitmap from the original image. Then you changed a single pixel in that invisible bitmap. So something happened but you couldn't see it. Jimi has given you one way to change the existing bitmap in the picturebox, which would allow you to see the change.

Comment: @idle_Mind Thank you for explaining what happened. I tried Jimi's way. But it also doesn't work. Maybe there is no weight for the color. So I have to choose a weight for color.
Maybe the weight is 0.

Comment: `there is no image in the picturebox`

Comment: @LarsTech I mean by `there is no image in the picturebox`. That in the propreties of the picturebox , I did not add image to `Image` proprety. I just add a backColor. I choosed the white color. To appear the image in white color. I can add a white image. But I choosed to add a backColor instead of adding an image.

Comment: What I'm saying is, try it with an image:  `PictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(100, 100)`  Add a refresh after your SetPixel call:  `PictureBox1.Refresh()`

Comment: If you don't want to use a Bitmap in your PictureBox, then an alternative would be to handle the `Paint()` event of the PB and draw in the supplied `e.Graphics` for that event. You'd could draw a "single pixel" by drawing a 1x1 red rectangle.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thank you very mush. I tried using `Paint` event and it worked!

Comment: If you need to easily move that red pixel, or you need to turn on/off a variable number of pixels, then the Paint() event might be a good approach. If you need to save the resulting image to the hard drive then the Bitmap approach might be better. They can both achieve the end goal probably, just in different ways.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can print pixel with Graphics

You need to import

```
Imports System.Drawing.Graphics
```

I added the drawline as the pixel is not really visible

```
Private Sub btn_Set_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Set.Click
    Dim pic1 As New Bitmap(200, 100)

    Dim gr As Graphics
    gr = Graphics.FromImage(pic1)
    Dim p As Pen = New Pen(Color.Red, 2)
    'printline
    gr.DrawLine(p, 30, 30, 45, 55)
    'Print pixel
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 55, 55, 1, 1)
    PictureBox1.Image = pic1
    PictureBox1.Update()
    PictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked! But I don't know why you wrote `gr.DrawLine(p, 30, 30, 45, 55)`

Comment: In  my high resolution monitor the pixel, was not really visible, but the line showed clearly, so i added it, as i described in my answer